# Как переменную JSTL  передать в скриплет jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Имеем переменную в jsp:

```
${time}
```

как её можно получить в jsp скриплете

```
<%
  String t = ${time};  <- вот тут
%>
```

Подскажите. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делал так

присволили значение переменной time в JSP

```
 <c:set var="time" value='2016.08.10 00:00:00'/>


<%
// запросили значение 
String date_input =(pageContext.getAttribute("time", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE)).toString(); 
// подготовка формата даты 
SimpleDateFormat format_data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat format = format_data;
Date date = format.parse(time);
format_data.applyPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
date_input=format.format(date);     
%>
```

Comment: не актуально ппц как давно))

Answer (score 2):

А вы уверены что вам действительно НЕОБХОДИМ скриптлет? Вы точно не можете подготовить данные в бине или до передачи управления JSP? Если точно нет на 100500%, то вы можете получить через один из контекстов (в зависимости от того, откуда взядась эта переменная). Это будет либо pageContext, либо session, либо application context или request context, которые доступны либо напрямую, либо через servlet context.

Comment: Хм. А спринг куда кладёт все переменные?)

Comment: Не могу сказать, я не спец по спрингу. Но думаю, вам следует подумать над концепцией. Необходимость в скриптлете на JSP почти наверняка указывает на ошибку дизайна.